# Can ChoETL csv reader read a column into an ICollection field?

Tags: c#, csv, etl, choetl

I have a csv with details about an order. There is one line per order, but in my code this translates to an `Order` object with an `ICollection<OrderLine> Lines` property. I need to read each order in to an `Order` object with the order line info added as an item to the `Lines` collection.

I am sending in a column mapping dictionary for the reader to use.

```
_orderMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"Customer", "CustomerName"},
                {"Model Number", "Lines.ElementAt(0).ModelNumber"},
                {"Ship Date", "ShipDate"},
                {"Quantity", "Lines.ElementAt(0).Quantity"},
                {"Warehouse", "Lines.ElementAt(0).WarehouseName"}
            };
```

Here's how I set up the `ChoCSVRecordConfiguration`:

```
var config = new ChoCSVRecordConfiguration<T>()
                .WithFirstLineHeader()
                .Configure(c => c.ThrowAndStopOnMissingField = false)
                .Configure(c => c.IgnoreEmptyLine = true)
                .Configure(c => c.FileHeaderConfiguration.IgnoreColumnsWithEmptyHeader = true);

            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                if (mapping.TryGetValue(header, out var propName))
                    config.Map(propName, header);
            }
```

where `mapping` is my mapping dictionary and `headers` are the csv sheet headers.
I tried using `Lines[0]` and `Lines.ElementAt(0)`, but `Lines` is still null. Is there a way to do this?

A sample csv:

[image: sample csv]

Code for Order object:

```
public class Order : OrderWithoutLines
    {
        public ICollection<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
    }

public class OrderLine
    {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerItemNumber { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int WarehouseId { get; set; }
    public string WarehouseName { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string FulfilledByPO { get; set; }
}
```

Order inherits from OrderWithoutLines which contains the rest of the Order info.

Comment: pls share sample csv file.

Comment: What is `OrderLine` class looks like? Does 'Order' class have any other members?

Comment: Here is one way to accomplish it, https://dotnetfiddle.net/soeyba

Comment: Nice, but I am trying to use the importer generically.
`using var reader = new ChoCSVReader<T>(stream, config)
                .WithMaxScanRows(2)
                .QuoteAllFields()
                .IgnoreFieldValueMode(ChoIgnoreFieldValueMode.Any);
            return reader.AsTypedEnumerable<T>();`

Comment: doesn't support out of the box with your req.

Comment: Yep thanks, I ended up restructuring my code to make this work. I made an interim CsvOrder class that has 1 OrderLine and then mapped to the properties of that OrderLine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Cinchoo for your help; straight from the source of the [ChoETL](https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL) library! This is not possible out of the box. I ended up using a `CsvOrder` class to import my orders with an `OrderLine` child class, and then I convert them to `Order` objects.